# What am I missing to get a profile page to include additional fields such as address, avatar, phone number

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I am using Ruby on Rails and utilized devise for my log in and registration.  After signing up, I get this error message:

```
NoMethodError in Devise::SessionsController#create undefined method profile_path' for #<Devise::SessionsController:0x007f9425b1f9c0>
```

I used `rails generate scaffold profile` and have the following code:

**profiles_controller.rb**

```
class ProfilesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_profile, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

 def profile

  end
  # GET /profiles
  # GET /profiles.json
  def index
    @profiles = Profile.all
  end

  # GET /profiles/1
  # GET /profiles/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /profiles/new
  def new
    @profile = Profile.new
  end

  # GET /profiles/1/edit
  def edit
   @profile = Profile.find_by user_id: current_user.id
   @attributes = Profile.attribute_names - %w(id user_id created_at updated_at)
  end

  # POST /profiles
  # POST /profiles.json
  def create
    @profile = Profile.new(profile_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @profile.save
        format.html { redirect_to @profile, notice: 'Profile was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @profile }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @profile.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /profiles/1
  # PATCH/PUT /profiles/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @profile.update(profile_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @profile, notice: 'Profile was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @profile }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @profile.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /profiles/1
  # DELETE /profiles/1.json
  def destroy
    @profile.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to profiles_url, notice: 'Profile was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_profile
      @profile = Profile.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def profile_params
      params[:profile]
    end
end
```

**application_controller.rb**

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
 # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
 # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
 protect_from_forgery with: :exception
 before_filter :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

protected

 def configure_permitted_parameters
   devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) << :name
   devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update) << :name
 end

  def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    profile_path(resource)
  end

  def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
    profile_path(resource)
  end
end
```

**profile.rb**

```
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
end
```

**user.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable 

  has_many :pins, dependent: :destroy



  validates :name, presence: true
has_one :profile
    before_create :build_profile #creates profile at user registration
end
```

**routes.rb**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :profiles, only: [:edit]

  resources :pins

  devise_for :users
  #devise_for :installs
  root "pins#index"
  get "about" => "pages#about"
```

Thanks.

Comment: To add new fields, you have to write migrations. I do not see what errors or problems you are facing. Can you explain your problem ?

Comment: Where is your error message?

Comment: I apoligize forgot to post the error: NoMethodError in Devise::SessionsController#create
undefined method `profile_path' for #<Devise::SessionsController:0x007f9425b1f9c0>

Extracted source (around line #15):
13
14
15
16
17
18
          

  def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    profile_path(resource)
  end

  def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)

Rails.root: /Users/DKL/Desktop/trueque

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/controllers/application_controller.rb:15:in `after_sign_in_path_for'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the plural: `profiles_path` rather than `profile_path`, in `application_controller.rb`.